# Heat semigroup dissipative

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, banach-spaces

Consider the heat semigroup on $L^1(\mathbb{R}).$ I would like to know if the generator of this semigroup is dissipative in the sense of [this definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_operator)

On $L^2$ it would be completely trivial, but I am having a hard time understanding the situation on $L^1.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Any generator of a strongly continuous semigroup of contractions is.

Let $P_t : L^1 \to L^1$ be the heat operators, $L$ the generator of the semigroup $(P_t : t \geqslant 0)$, and $D(L)$ its domain. Then $(P_t)$ is a strongly continuous semigroup of contractions, and so its resolvent $U_\lambda f = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} P_t f dt$ injectively maps $L^1$ onto $D(L)$, the inverse mapping being $\lambda - L$. Since the operator norm of $U_\lambda$ is $\lambda^{-1}$, we have $\lambda \|U_\lambda f\|_1 \le \|f\|_1$ for all $f \in L^1$, or, equivalently, $$\lambda \|g\|_1 \le \|(\lambda - L) g\|_1$$ for all $g \in D(L)$.

This is the *easy* part of the [Lumer–Philips theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumer%E2%80%93Phillips_theorem).

Comment: okay, now I must admit I asked the wrong question what I was actually wondering about is whether one can also use the equivalent characterization here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_operator#Equivalent_characterizations to show this. I very much appreciate your answer, but if you have an idea how to use this criterion, I would be happy to know.

Comment: If it is equivalent, I suppose one can use it. The Wikipedia page gives a reference to Prop. II.3.23 in the book by Engel and Nagel. The proof of this result tells us how to construct the corresponding linear functional. If $f \in L^1$, $F \in L^\infty$, $\|f\|_1 = \|F\|_\infty$ and $\int f F = \|f\|_1^2$, then $F(x) = \|f\|_1 |f(x)|^{-1} f(x)$ if $f(x) \ne 0$, and $F(x)$ is completely arbitrary when $f(x) = 0$, as far as $|F(x)| \leqslant \|f\|_1$. The proof tells us that we should choose $F(x) = -\|f\|_1 |L f(x)|^{-1} L f(x)$ when $f(x) = 0$ and $L f(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: thank you, I see that your $F \in L^{\infty}$ is in the admissible set, but is it clear to you why $(\Delta f,F)\le 0$?

Comment: @Zehner: In the general case: no, it is not, unless I take a look into the proof given in Engel–Nagel. Then I understand that in fact we work with $\lambda f-Lf$ for large $\lambda$, or $f-\varepsilon Lf$ for small $\varepsilon>0$, and we use the corresponding functional $c\operatorname{sign}(f-\varepsilon Lf)$. For the heat semigroup on the real line, however, you can simply set $F(x)=0$ when $f(x)=0$ and use the fact that $\int_a^b \operatorname{sign}(f(x)) f''(x)dx\le 0$ for any connected component $(a,b)$ of $Z = \{x : f(x) \ne 0\}$. (In this case $D(L)$ is equal to $W^{2,1}(\mathbf{R})$).

Comment: All that has been said so far is true. Let me only point to the fact that the heat semigroup is
* $L^2$-contractive
* $L^\infty$-contractive (by the Beurling-Deny-criteria)
* self-adjoint (so $L^\infty$-contractivity implies $L^1$-contractivity).